# PromQL - How to search a value column using last 5m?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, observability

I'm trying find a count of my errors in last 5 minutes with this query:

`count_over_time (MY_METRIC{id="X",app="XXX", state="Success"}==0 [5m])`

But i have a error: `"bad_data: 1:25: parse error: unexpected "(" in aggregation"`

The problem is `==0`, if I try: `count_over_time (MY_METRIC{id="X",app="XXX", state="Success"} [5m])`, return for me. But I need use `==0` because my metric state is fix and the value is dynamic.

For exemple, when i have a Error, my metric return like this:
`MY_METRIC{id="X",app="XXX", state="Success"} 0`
`MY_METRIC{id="X",app="XXX", state="Warning"} 0`
`MY_METRIC{id="X",app="XXX", state="Error"} 1`

Anyone can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: To avoid your immediate error you can add `:` to range selector `[5m:]` (and maybe wrap comparison into parentheses). But are you sure you need `count_over_time`? I feel like it's doing not what you think. Based on your description I'd try something like `count(last_over_time( (Mymetric.... == 0) [5m:] ))`